# Sqoop - Import max value query fails if used order by and limit 1

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, hdfs, sqoop

I have a simple Sqoop query which I am using to import the maximum value of the id of a table and store it in HDFS. Storing in HDFS was something the client asked for so I am going for it for multiple reasons.

To get the maximum I used

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://abc.com/sqoopemp \
--username root \
--password root \
--e 'select max(id) from emp WHERE $CONDITIONS' \
--target-dir sqooplastmax \
--m 1 \
--driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Above query gives me the required answer but I am thinking of using the following for performance reasons

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://abc.com/sqoopemp \
--username root \
--password root \
--query 'select id from emp oder by id limit 1 WHERE $CONDITIONS' \
--target-dir sqooplastmax1 \
--m 1 \
--driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

This query gives me an error and following is the error

```
    Warning: /usr/hdp/2.4.0.0-169/accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
16/06/05 15:50:06 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6.2.4.0.0-169
16/06/05 15:50:06 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
16/06/05 15:50:06 WARN sqoop.ConnFactory: Parameter --driver is set to an explicit driver however appropriate connection manager is not being set (via --connection-manager). Sqoop is going to fall back to org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager. Please specify explicitly which connection manager should be used next time.
16/06/05 15:50:06 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
16/06/05 15:50:06 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.4.0.0-169/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.4.0.0-169/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
16/06/05 15:50:06 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: select id from emp order by id desc limit 1 WHERE  (1 = 0)
16/06/05 15:50:06 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE  (1 = 0)' at line 1
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE  (1 = 0)' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3597)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3529)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1990)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2151)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2625)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2119)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2283)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:758)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:767)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:270)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:241)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForQuery(SqlManager.java:234)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:304)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1845)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1645)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:107)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:184)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:226)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:235)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:244)
16/06/05 15:50:06 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1651)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:107)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:184)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:226)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:235)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:244)
```

Issue obviously is with WHERE $CONDITIONS but I don't know where I am missing. The first free form query works but when I use it with order by and limit it does not work. Any help on the above will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query order seems to be incorrect (plus it has a typo):

```
select id from emp oder by id limit 1 WHERE $CONDITIONS
```

Should read:

```
select id from emp  WHERE $CONDITIONS order by id limit 1
```

Also this looks insecure if `$CONDITIONS` is externally set: Anybody can insert any code in `$CONDITIONS` with so called SQL injection.

Best way to handle the SQL injection is to split the $CONDITION in two parts:

1) The column name(s)
2) The value(s)

If Sqoop does not allow parametrized queries like this:

```
select id from emp  WHERE some_column=:columnValue order by id limit 1
```

Then there is two directions you can take:

A) Add verification code in front of the sqoop call

Or

B) Create a stored procedure in MySQL to check the validity of the query before executing it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and it worked and the additional point on the SQL injection. Could you please suggest how I should tackle SQL injection here ?